# Use non-laravel package league/csv in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, csv, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.4

I am trying to use the composer package league/csv in laravel 5.

In my controller there is the following use statement:

```
use League\Csv\Reader;
```

Then there is the following function:

```
public function import (Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'csv' => 'required|mimetypes:text/comma-separated-values,text/plain|mimes:csv,txt',
        ]);

        if ($request->file('csv') && $request->file('csv')->isValid())
        {
            $file = $request->csv->path();

            $csv = new Reader($file);
            echo'<pre>';var_dump($csv);exit;

        }
    }
}
```

The reader is loaded but I got the following error message:

```
Call to protected League\Csv\AbstractCsv::__construct() from context 'App\Http\Controllers\MyController'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like from the [documentation](https://csv.thephpleague.com/9.0/) you need to do something similar to this

```
$csv = Reader::createFromPath($request->csv->path(), 'r');
```

You cannot [instantiate the Reader](https://csv.thephpleague.com/9.0/connections/instantiation/) through the constructor since it's a `protected` [method](https://github.com/thephpleague/csv/blob/b9a4d39d8f8952947a7a5954489174bdd0104af5/src/AbstractCsv.php#L91).

Comment: Oh my god.. I thought it was a laravel problem. Please excuse me and thank you very much!